# Spark SQL: Where can I find a SQL syntax definition for sqlContext.sql?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Where can I find a formal syntax definition for the SQL that `sqlContext.sql()` accepts?
I would like to know what features and functionalities are available and how they map to the functions provided by `DataFrame` (and `DataSet`). For example, in `SELECT * FROM table` what is the table? A `DataFrame`?

Thanks!

Comment: start here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/SQLContext.html

Comment: also depends on your api. many use spark SQL (and I think this is also what you mean) when referring to spark-shell running  DF apis. ex: val `imps = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "false").option("inferSchema", "true").load(s"s3n://logs.xxxx.com/imp/2015/12/14/*")`
`val dummy     = imps.select("C0","C18","C7","C9","C33","C29"      ).registerTempTable("tblName")`
and now you can use sql syntax with: `sqlContext.sql("select C0,sum(C18) from tblName group by C0 limit 100")`

Comment: @ZahiroMor: Thanks for the example; it is now clear how tables are used. On the syntax: I checked the whole spark git repo and found a Java class (`SQLBaseParser`) that does the actual parsing, but from that it was not clear what is actually the formal definition of the SQL dialect. Yes, I could reverse engineer it from the Java code, but no, thanks.

Comment: I can also tell you that spark-sql aims to support all hive functionalities - you can read about it here :http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#compatibility-with-apache-hive. we now have rollup and windowed functionalities

Comment: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$

Comment: I would recommend hive documents , as mentioned by @ZahiroMor , spark supports all hive fucntionalities and requests,

Comment: I second (or third) the comments about Hive. When I have gotten stuck on something in the past, the Hive docs have always gotten me going the right direction.